# How can I remove the list items that Ive inputed from my list?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can add and remove the list items, but when I remove an item and add something else after, my previously deleted items are re-added to the list. How can I fix this to where it will delete the items and even when I add more items it will not add it to the list? Im pretty sure the problem is in my handleDelete function. Im using jQuery.

```
let skills;


const $button = $('button');
const $ul = $('ul');
const $input = $('input');



$button.on('click', handleAddSkill);
$ul.on('click', handleDelete);



init();

function init() {
    skills = [];
    render();
}

function handleAddSkill() {
    
    const skill = $input.val();
    
    if(skill) {
         
        const $skill = $(`<li><span>X</span>${skill}</li>`)
        
        skills.push($skill);
        
        $input.val('');
        )
        render()
    } else return;
}

function handleDelete() {
    $('li').click(function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
}

function render() {
    if(!skills.length) $ul.css('margin-bottom', '30px');
    else $ul.css('margin-bottom', '0px');

    $ul.html(skills);
}
```

Comment: You're removing the element from the DOM, but you're not removing it from your array. So when you re-`render()` the array, the values you _thought_ you deleted are being rendered. You need to modify your `handleDelete()` to remove the item from the `skills` array, not just from the DOM.

Comment: @Deannaleenormanmsncom Hey! Did you check my answer??

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that `handleDelete` function only removes the `<li>` from the DOM. It is still there in the `skills` array, so when you add an item again, `render` will be called and it will display all the items in the `skills` array and therefore you will add that list back. The following snippet is working as per your requirements.

```js
let skills;


const $button = $('button');
const $ul = $('ul');
const ul = document.querySelector("ul");
const $input = $('input');



$button.on('click', handleAddSkill);
ul.addEventListener("click", handleDelete, true);

init();

function init() {
  skills = [];
  render();
}

function handleAddSkill() {

  const skill = $input.val();

  if (skill) {

    const $skill = $(`<li id="${skills.length}"><span>X</span>${skill}</li>`)

    skills.push($skill);

    $input.val('');
    render();
  } else return;
}

function handleDelete() {
  $('li').click(function() {
    $(this).remove();
    skills.splice(Number(this.id), 1);
  });
}

function render() {
  if (!skills.length) $ul.css('margin-bottom', '30px');
  else $ul.css('margin-bottom', '0px');

  $ul.html(skills);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input>
<button>Add</button>
<ul></ul>
```

Also, there is another severe issue with your code, currently you click once on the `<li>` it won't get deleted, you need to click it twice and this is because when you click on the `<li>` there's no click listener for it. **It has to do with how event bubbling and capturing happens**.

In short first your program is looking for `<li>`s click listener, it finds none and then it moves to `<ul>`s click listener and here you actually create the click listener for `<li>`. So, next time when you click it will find click listener for `<li>`. To fix this move the click listener for `<ul>` to capturing phase by setting the third parameter for `addEventListener` as true. Unfortunately you cannot do this using jQuery as jQuery events can only be in bubbling phase.

If you want to read more about **Event Bubbling and Event Capturing**, I recommend reading this [article](https://medium.com/@shekhar2som/capturing-bubbling-in-js-events-cfc7d8735c29)